# Confused about the components of the metric's inverse in Schutz's text

Tags: general-relativity, differential-geometry

I'm self-studying GR with Schutz's text primarily, and try as I might there's this spot I'm stuck on.  For reference, this is from section 7.2 (physics in a slightly curved spacetime).

So, we are given the metric $ds$ in terms of the Newtonian potential $\phi$:
$$
ds^2=-(1+2\phi)dt^2+(1-2\phi)(dx^2+dy^2+dz^2)
$$

I'm good with the argument made that the 4-momentum of the particle is along the geodesic:  $\nabla_{\vec{p}}\vec{p}=0$, and how for the zero component of the equation, at nonrelativistic velocities we have:
$$
m\frac{d}{d\tau}p^0+\Gamma^0_{00}(p^0)^2=0
$$

Now, the part I don' understand, is when he shows the computation of the Christoffel symbol from the metric.  He says since $g_{ab}$ is diagonal, then $g^{ab}$ is also diagonal and its elements are the reciprocals of each other.  I'm good with all of that, but this step is where I'm having trouble:

$$
\Gamma^{0}_{00}=\frac{1}{2}g^{00}g_{00,0}=\frac{1}{2}\frac{1}{-(1+2\phi)}(-2\phi)_{,0}=\phi_{,0}+0(\phi^2)
$$

This is what I don't understand.  Wouldn't $g_{00,0}$ be $-(1+2\phi)_{,0}$, as from the original metric given, not $(-2\phi)_{,0}$?  And where does the squared term for $\phi$ come from?

Comment: $\frac{\partial}{\partial t} 1 =0$

Comment: Wait, I think I see now part of it.  $\frac{d}{d\tau}[-1(1+2\phi)]=-2\frac{d\phi}{d\tau}=(-2\phi)_{,0}$?  Wow don't know how I didn't see that.  But I'm still not seeing where the squared term comes from.

Comment: Yes, and for the second one, use the Taylor series expansion for $\frac{1}{1+2\phi}$. $O(\phi^2)$ means that it contains terms of order $\phi^2$ (and higher). This contribution is neglected because of the condition below (7.8) which imposes $|\phi| \ll 1$

Comment: Oh, O as in Big-O not the number zero.   That's occurred a couple other places and I was way confused.  Thanks much, I've been banging my head on this an embarrassingly long time.

Comment: Yeah, it's not zero. It stands for 'order'. So terms of order $\phi^2$ and above are neglected

Comment: Heck, + 1 just for self-studying GR from Schutz's text; my copy is well worn.